# Convert Python script to exe / command executable but be able to read from an editable .env file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, .env

Good afternoon all.

I hope that you are well.

I have a Python script that I would like to share with others, however it relies on the executable file being able to read a value from a .env file stored within the same location as where the executable is being ran from.  I am running Mac OSX.

Here is some example code :-

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

test_environment_variable = os.environ.get("TEST_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE")

print(test_environment_variable)
```

The aim is to convert my script into a command executable file and then for it to be able to read from an editable .env file within the same directory as the executable file.  If the .env file is edited and saved, the next time the executable is ran, the output will be the contents of the newly saved .env file.

I have converted my script to an executable using the following command :-

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

This results in a dist folder being created with the executable file in there.  If I place the .env file in the same directory as the executable file, then the output of the exe returns "None" whereas I would expect it to return "This is a new test environment variable" as per my .env file contents :-

```
TEST_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "This is a new test environment variable"
```

I can only assume that when the command application / executable file cannot find the .env path that is within the same directory as it and that this issue is due to the a problem with absolute vs relative paths.  Do I need to run pyinstaller with different switches in order to be able to make the executable "aware" of the path to look at for the .env file at any time it is loaded (it will always be in the same directory as the executable file in my use case)?  Alternatively, does my code need to be amended to be more definitive about the .env file location?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

The `load_dotenv()` function by default looks in the parent directory of the file that it is called from, and then continues to climb the directory tree until it finds a `".env"` file.  When used from a compiled pyinstaller app, the parent directory becomes the runtime directory, not the directory containing the executable file.

Since you know that the .env file will exist in the same folder as the executable file, you can use the `dotenv_path` keyword argument of the `load_dotenv` function to specify an absolute path to where the actual `.env` file is located.   A way to do this would be to use the `sys.executable` variable, which when used inside of a pyinstaller compiled application, points to the `exe` file.

For example:

```
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

exe_file = sys.executable
exe_parent = os.path.dirname(exe_file)
dotenv_path = os.path.join(exe_parent, ".env")

load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)

test_environment_variable = os.environ.get("TEST_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE")

print(test_environment_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be a better idea that your program accepts env/configuration file as input parameter to the program.

You should modify your program in a way that it *requires* env/config params. If a file is not passed, it would just error out.

Comment: Thank you Em for your suggestion.  It is much appreciated.  To elaborate a bit more on my side, the main script I have wrote is actually a GUI application using tkinter.  I am trying to make the application as user friendly as possible (for non-techy users).  The .env file will store an authentication token.  The user will click the executable file, a GUI will be launched, which will load the authentication token value (different per user) from the .env file and the code within the script will use that authentication token value.  Is your suggestion to make use of sys.argv or similar?  Thanks.

Comment: If its a GUI app then it would make much sense to let app manage the config/env file. A user shouldn't change the file directly. if they have to change anything in the file, they have to go through app's UI (Settings menu or something). The app can choose to save the env/config file in pre-determined location (regardless of the OS). Whenever a user makes a change, the app should write to the file and read from file. Thsi would allow app to manage multiple versions of file based on logged in user.